# Automate students tests run

Tags: python

I have a folders structure for some tasks, they are like this:

```
- student_id1/answers.py
- student_id2/answers.py
- student_id3/answers.py
- student_id4/answers.py
- ...
```

I have a main file: `run_tests.py`:

```
from student_id1.answers import run_test as test1
from student_id2.answers import run_test as test2
...


try:
    test1()
    print("student_id1: OK")
except Exception as ee:
    print("Error for student_id1")

try:
    test2()
    print("student_id2: OK")
except Exception as ee:
    print("Error for student_id2")
...
```

There can be more folders as they are adding with each new student. I would like to call all tests with a single command, but do not want to add so much lines with each new student.

How can I automate this?

Comment: Try writing a program that writes all those lines for you. A simple for range loop should be enough. Then run the generated code.

Comment: @Filip, this might work, but absolutely non-pythonic way :)

Comment: Slightly better than running eval in the actual generator :) I'd guess it results in very simple code, and since it's a fairly simple task, I guess Sarah is a beginner, so I tried to keep it simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `importlib` module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html

```
import os
import importlib

for student_dir in os.listdir():
    if os.path.isdir(student_dir):
        # here you may add an additional check for not desired folders like 'lib', 'settings', etc
        if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(student_dir, 'answers.py')):
            print("Error: file answers.py is not found in %s" % (student_dir))
            continue
        student_module = importlib.import_module("%s.answers" % student_dir)
        try:
            student_module.run_test()
            print("%s: OK" % student_dir)
        except Exception as ee:
            print("Error for %s" % student_dir)
```